# Node.js: Download a tar.gz from Github and write to file

Tags: node.js, https, tar, zlib, fs

I'm trying to download a tar.gz from Github and write it to the filesystem. My current code:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var zlib = require('zlib');

var file = fs.createWriteStream('zeromq-4.1.5.tar.gz');
var request = https.get('https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq4-1/releases/download/v4.1.5/zeromq-4.1.5.tar.gz', function(response) {
  response.pipe(zlib.createGzip()).pipe(file);
});
```

When I run `tar xzf zeromq-4.1.5.tar.gz`, I get the following error:

```
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
```

Comment: Why are you gzipping a tar that has already been gzipped? Just pipe the response directly to the writeStream.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that `https.get` doesn't follow redirects. The following resolved it for me:

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = require('url');

var TAR_URL = 'https://github.com/' + process.env.ZMQ_REPO + '/releases/download/v' + process.env.ZMQ + '/zeromq-' + process.env.ZMQ + '.tar.gz';
var FILE_NAME = 'zeromq-' + process.env.ZMQ + '.tar.gz';

function writeToFile(response) {
  response.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(FILE_NAME));
}

https.get(TAR_URL, function(response) {
  if (response.statusCode > 300 && response.statusCode < 400 && response.headers.location) {
    if (url.parse(response.headers.location).hostname) {
      https.get(response.headers.location, writeToFile);
    } else {
      https.get(url.resolve(url.parse(TAR_URL).hostname, response.headers.location), writeToFile);
    }
  } else {
    writeToFile(response);
  }
});
```